# How can I add a dynamic section to the footer of all my views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have inherited a legacy Rails application written years ago, running on version 2.x. I am still struggling with wrapping my head around some of the basic concepts of Rails and ActiveRecord.

I am to add a dynamic activity stream to the bottom of every page, listing the latest changes someone did.

To get the activity stream I have a giant SQL query of doom. In my postgres database I have turned said query into a simple database view (a virtual read-only table, basically) I can query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM recent_activity LIMIT 4
```

What is the appropriate way to prepare this data for use in the footer on every single page in my application?

Should it have its own model? Its own controller? Can I somehow include this on every page automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide some variable to the view layout with the content of this query.
A quick and dirty solution coming to mind would be to use the 'before_filter' in the ApplicationController, i.e

```
before_filter :get_footer

      def get_footer
        # do your sql query here and save it in an instance variable like @footer
      end
```

This should set the varieble @footer to the required value and make it accessible in the view.

You could then add a line to the global application layout that contains @footer (maybe format the output a little)